# How to check if a value on a csv file exist in another

Tags: python, csv

Suppose i have csv1 wc contains names so as csv2. Now i want to write another file named csv3 and the first column contains the names on csv1 and the 2nd column will write exist if name on csv1 is on csv2 and not exist if not on csv2.

Comment: I will recomend you to use pandas for this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GiovaniSalazar mentioned, `pandas` will make this easier. If your csv files aren't too big, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
# first, read in the csv files
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

# then, assuming the names are in a column called `name`, find the common names
df1['exists'] = df1.name.isin(df2.name)

# and, finally, write out dataframe 3
df1.to_csv('df3.csv', index=False)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create two lists. The first one contains the names of csv1 and the second one contains the names of csv2. With a for loop you can check if a name from csv2 is in csv1 and append it to a dictionary that you will add to your csv3 file.

```
csv3 = {}
for name in csv1:
    if name in csv2:
      csv3[name] = "Exists"
    else:
      csv3[name] = "Not Exist"
```

The other problem that you may have if how to open a csv file and read it or write on it. I can suggest you to search a little bit about Pandas. This is the tool that you must use if you are going to work with datasets like csv files

Answer (score 0):

This example I recommend if you have information many rows in your csv files. As you can see, I use pandas and numpy for the result ... pip install pandas and pip install numpy

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

csv1 = """
NAME
Jhon
Juan
Leo
"""
csv2 = """
NAME
Cris
Juan
Luis
"""
# If you are using csv then :   df_csv1 = pd.read_csv('myfilecsv1.csv'), sep=',') and df_csv2 = pd.read_csv('myfilecsv2.csv', sep=',')
df_csv1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv1), sep=',')
df_csv2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv2), sep=',')
df_csv1['Match'] = np.where(df_csv1.NAME == df_csv2.NAME, 'exist', 'not exist')
print(df_csv1)
# Save the result on csv file 
df_csv1.to_csv('csv3.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: There was a ValueError: Can only compare identically labeled Series object